# Good Resources on CorDbg & Mdbg

Tags: .net, debugging, cil, mdbg

I am looking for some good resources of information about the CorDbg & Mdbg debuggers in .NET as well as some stuff about MSIL(CIL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think MSDN might be a good resource to learn about that stuff:

- [Coredbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zb7c8d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [MDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx)
- [Compiling to MSIL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Also, you can try reading up on some of this stuff on Wikipedia:

- [Common Intermediate Language (CIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)